# Cronjob added but not working

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, cron, putty

I have a php script hello.php which is used to send notification to my android device under /var/www/html and have a server on Amazon EC2.
I am using putty and logged in via SSH.

- Ran crontab -e
- In the first line of vi editor typed: `* * * * * /bin/php /var/www/html/hello.php`
- pressed esc and then :wq and crontab-l lists the job also
- Every minute (since ***** is there) I get a mail which says

  `Could not open input file: var/www/html/hello.php`

The script is executing from the console, I tried `chmod 755 /var/www/html/hello.php`

Please help with this

Comment: Message seems clear. Why are you chmodding welcome.php, but putting hello.php in the cron?

Comment: Sorry for that, I tried it but while posting the question copied the line from the source from which I took help

Comment: @rjdown, I forgot to add a "/", chmodding is not showing any error, Please help

Comment: check your logs and make sure that all folders and file can be written to/check permissions.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, cron tries to access a file under "var/www/html/hello.php" which is relative, instead of "/var/www/html/hello.php" which is absolute.

Check your path in your cron file ?

Comment: path is /var/www/html/hello.php

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The only problem in my case was I should have used php instead of /bin/php.